# Wordpress check if you're on the current page (not menu)

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a little shortcode that acts like the custom menu widget, but I'm choosing the pages from a dropdown list, instead of creating a menus inside the wordpress (I'm also adding a color to it, so I can't just use regular wordpress menus widget).

So far so good, it's just one thing that's bothering me. I want to check if the page I'm on matches the one in my list (on the real page). I googled and searched a bit and found that with

```
$actual_link = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

I can get the current page I'm on (the link I see in my browser). Perfect!

So if I want to add a class called current page, all I need to see if my `$actual_link` matches with my selected link from the dropdown list.

I'm working this within a page bulder plugin The Creator, so I know how to create a working shortcode in it. My pages dropdown is created by making an array that will have page url as key and page name as a value. My loop is:

```
$args = array (
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order' => 'ASC',
);
$pages = get_posts($args);

$forms = array();
if(is_array($pages)){
    foreach ($pages as $page) {
        $forms[$page->url] = $page->post_title;
    }
}
```

And it works perfectly. Except that the url I get from this is of the form:

```
http://www.example.com/?page_id=150
```

Whereas I set my permalinks to be nice so the actual link in my browser is

```
http://www.example.com/my_page_name
```

The id is correct, and if I click on my 'menu' link I'll get to that page (desired result). But now I cannot just go and say:

```
$current = ($actual_link == $link) ? 'current_page' : '';
```

where `$link` is the variable that holds the link to the page from the dropdown, so that I can append this to my list to check if I'm on the current page (adds a current_page class). I need this class for the styling purposes - if I'm on the page that has this menu shortcode, next to the link that matches this page I'll get chevron (>).

So my question is, how to get the matching urls, no matter what permalink setting I use? Is there a way to specify this in the `get_posts()` query, or with the `$_SERVER[]` variable?

I am trying to avoid javascript with this one, and do everything server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found the answer.

I changed my query to

```
$args = array (
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order' => 'ASC',
);
$pages = get_posts($args);

$forms = array();
if(is_array($pages)){
    foreach ($pages as $page) {
        $forms[$page->ID] = $page->post_title;
    }
}
```

So that I can get page ID, then use

```
$link_out = get_permalink($link);

$current = ($actual_link == $link_out) ? 'current_page' : '';
```

And it works! :D

Answer (score 4):

You need to place `get_the_ID()` inside `get_permalink()` it will return the link which you have to match with `$actual_link`

```
$link = get_permalink(get_the_ID());
```

something like this.

Comment: Just wrote this :D I figured it out :D